# How to turn off damage camera shake in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the game Minecraft when your character is damaged the camera shakes. This causes motion sickness for some players. Is there a way to turn off camera shake?

Answer (score 3):

There is one such possibility to disable camera shake/tilting in response to damage. Sodium-Extra on Fabric (and Fabric only, also requiring Sodium) adds the option to disable hurtcam. These can be found on curseforge.
As far as I am aware, vanilla Minecraft does not have any option to toggle this functionality (which doesn't work properly since forever).